# "Permission Denied" when accessing private keys downloaded from S3 to elastic beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I stored Firebase Admin SDK credential into elastic beanstalk env from amazon S3 on app's deployment according to the official AWS doc.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-storingprivatekeys.html

When Firebase Admin SDK tries to access the key it raises error.

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/pki/tls/certs/my_cert.json'
```

How can I setup make it work?

Comment: Can you ssh into the EB instance and check who is able to access `/etc/pki/tls/certs/my_cert.json`? Guess, it is a `root` user? Your app on EB does not have access to `root` owned files by default.

Comment: What value should I put inside owner section instead of root? Would it be instance profile of the app on EB? @Marcin

Comment: I changed file owner and group to ec2-user and still getting the same error

Comment: If the file is in the correct location you can start verifying

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform 2 steps:

- .ebextensions/privatekey.config as described in [your doc url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-storingprivatekeys.html). You can check the beanstalk logs (of cfn-init logs if you can SSH) to verify if the .ebextensions script is executed correctly
- The beanstalk should be able to access the S3 bucket where the keys are stored.

Point 2 in more detail:

The instance profile assigned to your environment's EC2 instances must have permission to read the key object from the specified bucket. Verify that the instance profile has permission to read the object in IAM, and that the permissions on the bucket and object do not prohibit the instance profile. You can test this by SSH'n inside the EC2 which belongs to the Beanstalk environment and execute: `aws s3 ls s3://your-bucket/with-key`. After that you can try to download the key. This is exactly the same what your ebextensions scripts tries to do. The ebextensions script will fail if it's not allowed to.

Comment: I both set permissions for S3 bucket and instance profile and still get the same error

Comment: I ssh into the server and confirmed the credential file was there.  Does this mean that permissions to read from s3 is setup correctly?

Comment: Then your beanstalk was able to download the file from S3 so that part seems fine. Now you can start checking which permissions the file needs on the disk. You can change permissions with chmod to test and update the "mode" configuration in your ebextionsscript

Comment: I ssh into the server using EB CLI. My terminal was showing I'm logged in as 'ec2-user'. 
Since I changed script to download credential form S3, credential file owner is now ec2-user. However the directory the credential file is in did not have read permisson for ec2-user so  I tried to change the permission using chmod but command was rejected since I had no permission(to change permission of dir).

Comment: What if you set the permission like here to root https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-storingprivatekeys.html